# ggplot - x-axis shows data beyond specified range for longer time periods

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

Here's some sample data for a company's Net revenue split by two cohorts:

```
data <- data.frame(dates = rep(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 48), each = 2),
                   revenue = rep(seq(10000, by = 1000, length.out = 48), each = 2) * rnorm(96, mean = 1, sd = 0.1),
                   cohort = c("Group 1", "Group 2"))
```

I can show one year's worth of data and it returns what I would expect:

```
start = "2000-01-01"
end = "2000-12-01"

ggplot(data, aes(fill = cohort, x = dates, y = revenue)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = NULL)) +
    xlab("Month") + 
    ylab("Net Revenue") +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(revenue, 0)), vjust = -0.5, size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 25)) + 
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", limits = as.Date(c(start, end))) +
    ggtitle("Monthly Revenue by Group") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BFC4", "#F8766D"))
```

[image]

But if I expand the date range to two years or more and rerun the graph, it shows additional months on both sides of the x-axis despite not displaying any information on the y-axis.

```
start = "2000-01-01"
end = "2001-12-01"
#rerun the ggplot code from above
```

[image]

Note the non-existant data points for 1999-12-01 and 2002-01-01. Why do these appear and how can I remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many (all?) of the `scale_*` functions take `expand=` as an argument. It's common in R plots (both base and `ggplot2`) to expand the axes just a little bit (4% on each end, I believe), I think so that none of the lines/points are scrunched up against the "box" boundary.

If you include `expand=c(0,0)`, you get what you want.

(BTW: you have mismatched parens. Fixed here.)

```r
ggplot(data, aes(fill = cohort, x = dates, y = revenue)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = NULL)) +
    xlab("Month") + 
    ylab("Net Revenue") +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(revenue, 0)), vjust = -0.5, size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 25)) + 
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", limits = as.Date(c(start, end)), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    ggtitle("Monthly Revenue by Group") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BFC4", "#F8766D"))
```

[image: better ggplot]

Comment: (Default expansion depends on the scale; 5% for continuous scale, 0.6 units for discrete, at least in ggplot.)

Comment: I suspected that the 4% in my head was just based on base-graphics. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly the issue is but if you change from "Date" class on x-axis to any other it seems to work as expected. Also filtering the data for the specific range before passing it to `ggplot`.

For example in this case changing dates to month-year format,

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

start = as.Date("2000-01-01")
end = as.Date("2001-12-01")
all_fac <- c(outer(month.abb, 2000:2001, paste, sep = "-"))

data %>%
  filter(between(dates, start, end)) %>% 
  mutate(dates = factor(format(dates, "%b-%Y"),levels = all_fac)) %>% 
  ggplot() + aes(fill = cohort, x = dates, y = revenue) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  xlab("Month") + 
  ylab("Net Revenue") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(revenue, 0))) + 
  ggtitle("Monthly Revenue by Group") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1), plot.title = 
  element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BFC4", "#F8766D"))
```

[image]

Please beautify/change the labels on the bars.